# Paste clipboard in outlook email in normal order

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have 5 userforms for an email. The workflow goes like this:

```
create new email

userform1.show
user selects the fields
automatic printscreen is inserted in the text

userform2.show
user selects the fields
automatic printscreen is inserted in the text

userform3.show
user selects the fields
automatic printscreen is inserted in the text

userform4.show
user selects the fields
automatic printscreen is inserted in the text

userform5.show
user selects the fields
automatic printscreen is inserted in the text
```

My problem is that in the end, the email will look like this:

```
userform1 selected fields
userform2 selected fields
userform3 selected fields
userform4 selected fields
userform5 selected fields

print screen 5
print screen 4
print screen 3
print screen 2
print screen 1
```

Is there a way to make the print screens appear in the correct order?

Here is the code that copies the clipboard for the first userform ( the print screen is from another application )

```
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

With objItem

         Set olInsp = .GetInspector
         Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
         Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
         oRng.collapse 1
         objItem.Display
         objItem.Visible = True
         objItem.HtmlBody = "<br><br>" & objItem.HtmlBody

         On Error Resume Next
         oRng.Paste

         objItem.HtmlBody = "<br>" & objItem.HtmlBody

         Dim myOutlook As Object
         Set myOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
         myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Activate

End With
```

I made the cursor to move to the end of the mail but the paste doesn't work at all

```
Dim objCurrentMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
Dim objWordRange As Word.Range
Dim VarPosition As Variant

    'Only work if the current email is using word editor
    Set objCurrentMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objWordDocument = objCurrentMail.GetInspector.WordEditor


       VarPosition = objWordDocument.Range.End - 1000
       Set objWordRange = objWordDocument.Range(VarPosition, VarPosition)
       objWordRange.Select

    keybd_event VK_DOWN, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_V, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_V, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
```

Comment: Can you add the code that copies the print screens into the email?

Comment: You probably have to move the cursor from the start to the end of the body of objItem to the end. With Word VBA to position the cursor . https://word.tips.net/T000120_Jumping_to_the_Start_or_End_of_a_Document.html  http://software-solutions-online.com/word-vba-move-cursor-to-end-of-document/ With the to be avoided Sendkeys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775872/email-how-do-i-place-cursor-at-the-end-of-the-body-text.

Comment: I made the cursor to move to the end of the mail but the paste doesn't work at all

Comment: You are aware that `oRng.collapse 1` moves the selection to the **start** of oRng? `Const wdCollapseStart = 1`, `Const wdCollapseEnd = 0` -- I would first try it with `wdCollapseEnd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is code here to move the cursor to the end http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/determine-cursor-position/

```
Public Sub SetCursor()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Dim range As Word.range
    Dim pos As Long

    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Doc = Ins.WordEditor
    If Not Doc Is Nothing Then
        pos = Doc.range.End - 1
        Set range = Doc.range(pos, pos)
        range.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Your code could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub pasteAtEnd()

Dim olInsp As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

Dim pos As Long
Dim objItem As Object

Set objItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

With objItem

    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.range

    objItem.Display
    'objItem.HTMLBody = "<br><br>" & objItem.HTMLBody
    objItem.HTMLBody = objItem.HTMLBody & "<br><br>"

    pos = wdDoc.range.End - 1
    Set oRng = wdDoc.range(pos, pos)
    oRng.Select

    MsgBox "Cursor should be at end of the mail body."

    'On Error Resume Next ' Use proper error handling
    oRng.Paste

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is what i was searching and it works 100%.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

if that does not work, click on the email window and hit ctrl-v to paste the content of the clipboard

```
Sub testPaste()

    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    outMail.Display (False)                      ' modeless

    Dim wd As Document
    Set wd = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    WordBasic.SendKeys "{prtsc}"   ' do screenshot  may or may not work on your pc
    wd.Range.Paste                 ' paste from clipboard

    Set wd = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

it is a "proof of concept" of sorts

i hope it works for you

there is a place in "addTextToMessage" where the program stops,

and you do a screenshot, then hit F5 to continue

the program also inserts a picture from a folder if you need (set path to fit your system)

```
Const uf1 = "userform1 selected fields"          ' sample userform text
Const uf2 = "userform2 selected fields"
Const uf3 = "userform3 selected fields"
Const uf4 = "userform4 selected fields"
Const uf5 = "userform5 selected fields"

Sub fillEmail()

    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    outMail.To = "example@example.com"
    outMail.Subject = "Testing inline images"
    outMail.Display (False)                      ' modeless

    Dim wordDoc As Document
    Set wordDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    wordDoc.Paragraphs.Space1                    ' format paragraph
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.SpaceBefore = 0           ' single-spaced ... etc
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.SpaceAfter = 0

    addTextToMessage wordDoc, uf1                ' these simulate the
    addTextToMessage wordDoc, uf2                ' five userforms boxes
    addTextToMessage wordDoc, uf3                ' you could pass the wordDoc reference
    addTextToMessage wordDoc, uf4                ' to each userform and have the userform
    addTextToMessage wordDoc, uf5                ' call the "addTextToMessage"

    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing


End Sub


Sub addTextToMessage(wd As Document, uf As String)

'    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------"
'    Debug.Print "                 uf : " & uf
'    Debug.Print "wd.Paragraphs.Count : " & wd.Paragraphs.Count
'    Debug.Print " wd.Sentences.Count : " & wd.Sentences.Count
'    Debug.Print "wd.Characters.Count : " & wd.Characters.Count
'    Debug.Print "       wd.Range.End : " & wd.Range.End
'    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------"

    wd.Range.InsertAfter (uf)
    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    Stop

' ------------------------------
' do screenshot here then hit F5
' ------------------------------
    wd.Characters.Last.Paste
    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

' this inserts a picture from folder
' the userforms could place pictures in a folder

    wd.Characters.Last.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
    FileName:="C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Temp\picture.png", _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True

    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter


'    Debug.Print "wd.Paragraphs.Count : " & wd.Paragraphs.Count
'    Debug.Print " wd.Sentences.Count : " & wd.Sentences.Count
'    Debug.Print "       wd.Range.End : " & wd.Range.End


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, although your code is good, I can't get the hold of it. It works on 50% of the cases - i don't know why... Thank you for the your time.

Answer (score 0):

here is updated code

create a userform with five buttons

paste this into the form code

it represents the five user forms that you mentioned

you can click the buttons in any sequence, yet the resulting email is always in sequence

NOTE: do a screenshot, or copy some graphic into clipboard before clicking buttons

```
' test userForm code

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' extra "demo" code in this sub
    ' see CommandButton2_Click sub for simplest code needed

    Dim rng As word.Range
    Set rng = emailTables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range

'    rng.Select                               ' debug

    rng.InsertAfter "1st line of response from userForm #1" & vbCrLf
    rng.InsertAfter "2nd line of response from userForm #1" & vbCrLf

    Set rng = emailTables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range

'    rng.Select                               ' debug

    rng.InsertAfter "screenshot from" & vbCrLf
    rng.InsertAfter "userForm #1" & vbCrLf
    rng.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

'    rng.Words(rng.Words.Count).Select        ' debug
'    rng.Words(rng.Words.Count - 1).Select    ' debug

    rng.Words(rng.Words.Count - 1).Paste     ' paste screenshot

'   insert picture from disk
'   emailTables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\js135001\AppData\Local\Temp\F4C97A0.png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True

    Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
'

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    emailTables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertAfter "response from userForm #2"
    emailTables(2).Cell(2, 1).Range.Paste      ' paste screenshot

End Sub
'

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    emailTables(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.InsertAfter "response from userForm #3"
    emailTables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range.Paste      ' paste screenshot

End Sub
'

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    emailTables(1).Cell(4, 1).Range.InsertAfter "response from userForm #4"
    emailTables(2).Cell(4, 1).Range.Paste      ' paste screenshot

End Sub
'

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

    emailTables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range.InsertAfter "response from userForm #5"
    emailTables(2).Cell(5, 1).Range.Paste      ' paste screenshot

End Sub
'

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    UserForm1.Caption = "do a screenshot before clicking buttons"
    CommandButton1.Caption = "UserForm1 response"
    CommandButton2.Caption = "UserForm2 response"
    CommandButton3.Caption = "UserForm3 response"
    CommandButton4.Caption = "UserForm4 response"
    CommandButton5.Caption = "UserForm5 response"
End Sub
```

put this code into a module and run it

```
' main code

Public emailTables As word.Tables                ' parameter passing to UserForms
'

Sub testEmail()                                  ' run me

    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    outMail.Display (False)                      ' modeless

    Dim wd As Document
    Set wd = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    For i = 0 To 9                               ' anchors for placing the two tables
        wd.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    Next

    ' at this point, here is what the document contains:
    ' 1 Section / 11 Paragraphs / 1 Sentence / 11 Words / 11 Characters

    ' replace 4th character with a table ... same with 8th character

    ' place 2nd table first, because the 8th character would fall in the middle of the first table (if the 1st table was placed first)

    wd.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Characters(8), NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    wd.Tables.Add Range:=wd.Characters(4), NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

    MsgBox "please acquire a screenshot before clicking any of the buttons"

    Set emailTables = wd.Tables
    UserForm1.Show

    Set wd = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

enjoy

Comment: Hi, your code works only with text from clipboard not with the images from clipboard. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: if i have text in the clipboard, then it pastes text for me also ... please make sure that you have an image in the clipboard ... do Printscreen  ... or start ms paint, draw something then copy a portion of the the image ... then click one of the five buttons

Comment: please try the snippet that i included  (testPaste)