# Paste Text in specified position

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have code from searches modified for my need.

I need to position the paste under the "Conditions" text in the xOutMsg variable. It is pasting into the first line in the email.

How do I paste on the next line after the word "Conditions"?

```
Sub PrepareConditionsEmail()
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSel As Word.Selection
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xOutMsg As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xOutMsg = "<br /><br /><b><u>Conditions:</b></u><br /><br />" & "<b><u> </b></u><br />"
With xOutMail
    '.To = "Email Address"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Conditions"
    .HTMLBody = xOutMsg
    .Display
End With
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set objDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
objSel.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteText, _
Placement:=wdInLine, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste clipboard in outlook email in normal order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693988/paste-clipboard-in-outlook-email-in-normal-order)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to parse the message and insert your own text or markup there. The [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody) property sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Use the `InStr` function which returns a long specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another. After you get the keyword position you may insert your substring right after the keyword.

```
 InStr(mail.HTMLBody, "keyword", 1)
```

Read more about the [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) in MSDN.

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

There is no need to mix `HTMLBody` and `WordEditor` approaches together. You can choose a single way and use it.