# Outlook - programmatically modify email currently being composed/edited

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

For valid personal reasons** I am trying to construct a macro that clears out the To, CC, Subject and Body of the email being replied to (in compose mode?). What I have below works on an email being READ, but it does not work on an email being MODIFIED/COMPOSED.

What must be changed for the macro to work on an email being composed/edited?

```
Sub ClearEmail()
    Dim olExplorer As Explorer
    Dim olSelection As Selection
    Dim email As MailItem
    Dim strSig As String, Sig As String

    Set olExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set olSelection = olExplorer.Selection
    Set email = olSelection.Item(1)

    email.To = ""
    email.CC = "team@example.com"

    email.Subject = ""
    email.HTMLBody = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Hello"
End Sub
```

<sup>**</sup> <sub>*My Exchange profile is messed up, has been for weeks, and the part-time Exchange admin cannot get to it anytime soon. The only way I can successfully send an email is to open an existing email from the group Inbox, hit Reply To All, clear out the fields and add my signature. Then I can edit as desired and send it with no problems. (Emails I simply compose and send get stuck in the Outbox and are never sent - there are dozens of them.) I have been doing this manually for weeks.*</sub>
<sub>*I am not an Outlook/VBA programmer so please forgive me for not knowing the right terminology.*</sub>

Sources:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628044-Insert-text-into-current-outlook-message

Comment: Set email = ActiveInspector.currentItem

Comment: The tiny text below your code says you cannot send emails you composed; you must edit an existing email. Your code edits the first or only selected email directly. Have you tried creating a copy of the original email and editting the copy? Add `Dim emailCopy As MailItem` and `Set emailCopy = email`.

Comment: About not being able to compose new emails - have you tried using Outlook in safe mode `outlook.exe /safe`? It could be some Outlook Addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows editing the email currently being composed:

```
Dim theEmail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set theEmail = oInspector.CurrentItem
```

Reference:

[Working with current open email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476986/working-with-current-open-email)