# How to Set Outlook Mailitem To Active Message Being Composed that is not in its own window?

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I set a `MailItem` variable to an active message being composed, if the message is not in its own window (i.e. within Outlook).

I have seen [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989779/outlook-programmatically-modify-email-currently-being-composed-edited) that explain how to set the variable to an open window such as this:

```
Dim theEmail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector
Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set theEmail = oInspector.CurrentItem
```

This works when a message draft is a window not if the draft is within Outlook.

How can I reference an active draft that is not a new window?

I've seen posts saying `Set theEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` however this references the received message being replied to, not the draft of the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse`. Explorer can be retrieved from `Application.ActiveExplorer`.

Comment: That's what I needed. For anyone looking for a signle line... this will do it: `Set aMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse`