# Link or copy an individual email in Outlook to MS Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, email, outlook, hyperlink

We have a case management application hosted on an Azure SQL database, front end MS Access, which contains a table of diary events. We would like to be able to link each diary record to a specific email in Outlook. Ideally this would be initiated from within Outlook, with the user selecting an email and choosing an action to create a record in the database with a link to the email, which could then be clicked in the front end to open. Is this possible?

Alternatively Outlook could create a new record in the SQL database and dump email attributes such as Sent, SentBy, Subject, Body etc. into a table of text fields.

Note we **don't** want to create or edit any emails from the application, we just want users to be able to quickly see the contents of existing emails flagged as relating to that case.

Can anyone please give us some pointers in the best way to achieve this. Apologies for the newbie question, fairly new to Azure and never written any Outlook VBA.

Thanks for any help!
Jim

Comment: You can probably just import emails from your email account by using imap or cdo and then they will magically arrive in your case handling software

Comment: We don't want to just import emails as not all emails will relate to cases. We only want users to choose specific ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with current open email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476986/working-with-current-open-email)

Comment: You can probably adopt the macro from the above duplicate and then lookup on how to add stuff into database from vba

Comment: thanks @siggemannen. I have now changed focus a little to get the user to initialise the action from within our Access application, but this might help.